# Difference between the term agenda and Todo list

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have frequently seen the term **Meeting Agenda** being used at several places 
The etymological definition of Agenda is nothing but **To do list** 
If agenda is simply a todo list kind of things why is this special word used? Or what else does the word agenda communicate apart from a simple todo list

Comment: _Agenda_ is the formal term always used for official meetings.  If you make a personal list of things you need to do, you could call it a to-do list.

Comment: In general, an ***agenda*** is a list of *things to be **discussed***, whereas a ***to-do list*** is a list of *things to be **done***. Any dictionary should make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

"To do list" might be common terminology in workplaces, but it is an informal term. It is a list of tasks that need to be done. More formal terms for a 'to do list' include a *work list, schedule,* or *itinerary*.

An 'agenda' is not the same as a 'to do list'. It is defined as "a program of things to be done or considered". For example, it can be a list of subjects to be discussed at a meeting. As a program of things to be *done*, an agenda tends to be far more high-level than a 'to do list'. For example, an organisation's agenda may broadly outline their goals, but a 'to do list' might specifically detail the tasks required to achieve those goals.